# Problems installing pyinstaller

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyinstaller

I tried pip install and received this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.5.24)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\sinwe\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
```

I then installed using setup.py

To check whether it is installed, in cmd:

```
pyinstaller --version
```

and I received this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sinwe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyinstaller==4.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')())
  File "C:\Users\sinwe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
StopIteration
```

Could anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the `pip list` command?

Comment: Try `pip uninstall pyinstaller` and then try `pip install pyinstaller`. Maybe that works

Comment: pip list included pyinstaller 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall `pyinstaller` using:

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

in the cmd, and upgrade `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then try to install `pyinstaller` again:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Comment: Other threads have noted that pyinstaller installed through setup.py cannot be pip uninstalled. I got the following error:

ERROR: Cannot uninstall pyinstaller 4.5.1, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pyinstaller==4.5.1'.